# How to use hint when load csv and merge data in Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, merge, load, hint

Suppose 58 million nodes and 100 million relationships already existed in the database.

Then I want to load a delta batch data which contains 1.3 million nodes and 1 million relationships via LOAD CSV method like below:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///path/to/data.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR '\t' 
MERGE (n:Person {cstid: row.cstid}) 
ON CREATE SET n.name = row.name 
ON MATCH SET n.name = row.name;
```

Also, there was a unique constraint on :Person(cstid), and I don't want to use it. So I tried to use the SCAN hint like below:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///path/to/data.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR '\t' 
MERGE (n:Person {cstid: row.cstid}) 
USING SCAN n:Person
ON CREATE SET n.name = row.name 
ON MATCH SET n.name = row.name;
```

But Neo4j just throw an warning, terminate the request and exit directly:

```
WARNING: Invalid input 's': expected 'n/N' (line 3, column 2 (offset: 154))
"using scan n:Person"
  ^
```

This phenomenon also exists if I specify the INDEX hint:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///path/to/data.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR '\t' 
MERGE (n:Person {cstid: row.cstid}) 
USING INDEX n:Person(cstid)
ON CREATE SET n.name = row.name 
ON MATCH SET n.name = row.name;
```

So... Does Neo4j support using hint in MERGE clause?

Neo4j: 3.2.0 CE

Answer (score 1):

No, neo4j currently does not support the `USING` clause with the `MERGE` clause.

However, this logically equivalent query should work:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///path/to/data.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR '\t' 
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Person {cstid: row.cstid}) 
USING SCAN n:Person
FOREACH(ignored IN CASE WHEN n IS NULL THEN [1] END | CREATE (n:Person {cstid: row.cstid}))
SET n.name = row.name;
```

The `FOREACH` clause is a hack for creating the node if it does not exist. And, since you always want to `SET` the `name` property, we just do that.

Comment: What is [1] stand for?

Comment: It is a collection containing a single value (that is ignored), which causes the operations after the `|` to be executed (once, in this case). `FOREACH` does nothing if it is asked to iterate over a `NULL` value or an empty collection.